# How do I make a Go gRPC work with standard IO on the server side?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am a freshman of gRPC, and here is my problem. I'm trying to write a service to expose `myOwnService` into a gRPC service per the following service method:

```
rpc HighFive (stream HighRequest) returns (stream HighReply) {}
```

The server-side code is as follows:

```
func (s *server) HighFive(stream pb.Greeter_HighFiveServer) error {    
    // Oops, don't know how to do here ...
    myOwnService(stdin io.ReadCloser, stdout io.WriteCloser)
    return nil
}

func myOwnService(stdin io.ReadCloser, stdout io.WriteCloser) error {    
    // read input from stdin, do something, the  write result to stdout
    ...
    return nil
}
```

As you can see above, I have no idea how to make `stream` work with `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` in my original service, so that the caller of the `HighFive` gRPC service can read and write data just like calling `myOwnService` normally.

[Update] My current messages are like this, but you can change them if necessary:

```
message HighRequest {
  bytes content  = 1;
}

message HighReply {
  bytes content  = 1;
}
```

Comment: grpc streams are streams of Protocol Buffer messages, not raw bytes (as what `myOwnService` expects). In order for this to work, you need to define how HighRequest gets converted to a byte slice and how a byte slice gets converted to HighReply.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the gRPC Basics tutorial section on Bidirectional streaming RPC](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go.html#bidirectional-streaming-rpc), each call to your `stream` parameter's `Recv` method will give you a decoded `HighRequest` message, *not* a byte stream, as you're expecting for your `myOwnService` function.

Now, if your `HighRequest` message contains a field of types `bytes` or `string`, you may wish to feed that field's content into `myOwnService` as the `stdin` parameter by wrapping the raw `[]byte` value via [`bytes.NewReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader).

I see, though, that `myOwnService` demands an `io.ReadCloser`. I don't know why you'd expect `myOwnService` to close its input parameter, but I'll trust you well enough that you need it to then recommend using [`ioutil.NopCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser) to satisfy that demand trivially.

Sketching:

```
// Next tag: 2
message HighRequest {
  bytes content = 1;
}

func (s *server) HighFive(stream pb.Greeter_HighFiveServer) error {
  for req, err := stream.Recv(); {
    if err != nil {
      if err == io.EOF {
        return nil
      }
      return err
    }
    in := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(req.Content))
    out := /* ... */
    if err := myOwnService(in, out); err != nil {
      return err
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've understand how you deal with input. But how to redirect output to the stream since it is a bio-direction rpc service.

Comment: I was thinking about what you might be trying to do last night, and I realized that maybe you'd want to concatenate all of the input fragments received in your message stream and present them together as the input stream to your `myOwnService` function. That's possible, though more complicated than what I showed above.

Comment: For output, you could supply a custom `io.Writer` to `myOwnService` that buffers some number of bytes, then writes them out in a `HighReply` message. You would send as many `HighReply` messages as necessary until there was no more buffered data that `myOwnService` had written. Again, this is fiddly, but certainly possible. Coaxing out how to transform a message stream to an `io.Reader` or an `io.Writer` to a message stream warrant separate questions here.

Comment: Now I used a pipe to capture output: `r, w, _ := os.Pipe(); myService(in, w)`, seems work